# JAXB Marshalling Different Elements with @XMLAnyElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I'm trying to do something like this.

```
<root>
    <Element1>
    <Element2>
    <Element3>
        <Subroot1>
</root>
```

My root class is like this

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Root {
    private List<Object> elements;

    @XmlAnyElement
    public List<Object> getElements
    {
        return elements;
    }
}
```

My Element classes are like this

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Element1 {

    public String value;
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

but when I try to marshall this I get this error back

```
java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this context.
```

I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you expecting to have a list of elements under root? What is the structure of Element3 and is it different from other ? Also are you trying to manually build these POJOs to match the requirement?

Comment: Basically it's a list of different elements. I'm building the POJO to match a requirement but the requirement is, sometimes it will contain elements 1 and element 2, some times it will contain elements 1 and 3. Or something in those combinations. I want to be able to just add them into the List